# What about the middle terms in this computation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix and $u,v$ be real ortoghonal vectors, $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$.
On my notes I wrote:
$$(au-bv)^T A(au-bv) = a^2 (u^T Au) + b^2 (v^T A v).$$
What about the middle terms?
It seems that here the middle terms
$$-ab (u^T Av)-ab(v^T Au)=0.$$
Could anyone please help me to understand why?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that you have written in your notes is not generally correct. For instance, take $u = (1,0)^T, v = (0,1)^T$, and
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&3}.
$$
Verify that
$$
(au - bv)^TA(au - bv) = 2a^2 + 3b^2 - 2ab.
$$

---

For the specific case that $a = u_n$ and $b = v_n$, consider
$$
u = (1,-2)^T, \quad v = (2,1)^T
$$
with the same matrix $A$. If we take $a = -4$ and $b = 3$, we get
$$
(au^T - bv)^TA(au - bv) = 9a^2 + 15b^2 - 10ab \neq 
9a^2 + 15b^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The statement is not correct also if I consider the special case in which $a= v_n$ and $b=u_n$, where $v_n, u_n$ denotes the n-th component of $v$ and $u$ respectively?

Comment: @C.Bishop I'm not sure what you mean there. Are you saying that $v = (a,a,\dots,a)^T$?

Comment: No, I mean if I take $a$ as the real number which correspond exactly to n-th component of the vector $v=(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ and similarly $b= u_n$.

Comment: The statement is indeed incorrect even in this special case